# How can I repair Windows XP virtually?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, system-restore

I want to repair my Windows XP, but my laptop's DVD ROM doesn't work, and all the time I've had to boot from a USB drive to install an OS. So now I want to repair Windows XP due to some problems.

I use Magic Disk virtual DVD ROM, but when I repaired while my DVD ROM was still working, the driver of Magic Disk was uninstalled by setup. So now I don't know exactly how to fix this problem by USB because every time it prompts for one of two steps

> 1: Boot from USB for 1st setup, i.e., Console part.
>   2: Boot from USB for 2nd setup, i.e., GUI part.

So I'm nervous that I will do something wrong that cost me a reinstall. I'd prefer the way of virtual repair, if it is possible, otherwise I'd appreciate knowing about how to repair through USB.

Comment: What is actually wrong with your system? Someone may be able to help/suggest a fix without requiring you to even need a disk

Comment: Actually its auto-run is not working, trying to update the IE6 to IE8 always stuck up, not able to create a dial-up using Bluetooth. Have I should to update this in my question?

Comment: No need to update... Right... IE6 -> IE8, maybe ask another question... Try from update and read the logs. Auto Run, check the registry or right click on the optical drive or look under "set program access and defaults" and  for Bluetooth, try removing the device in device manager and readding, or even trying a different bluetooth stack such as bluesolleil or Toshiba... Or even reinstalling/activating the Microsoft stack.

Comment: @William if you post it as answer I'll accept it....yeah Big guy you helped me and drag out from this dig Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments...

> What is actually wrong with your system? Someone may be able to
>   help/suggest a fix without requiring you to even need a disk

– William Hilsum

> Actually its auto-run is not working, trying to update the IE6 to IE8
>   always stuck up, not able to create a dial-up using Bluetooth. Have I
>   should to update this in my question?

– avirk

> No need to update... Right... IE6 -> IE8, maybe ask another
>   question... Try from update and read the logs. Auto Run, check the
>   registry or right click on the optical drive or look under "set
>   program access and defaults" and for Bluetooth, try removing the
>   device in device manager and readding, or even trying a different
>   bluetooth stack such as bluesolleil or Toshiba... Or even
>   reinstalling/activating the Microsoft stack.

– William Hilsum

Comment: And +1 for save me.